# jquery ui selectmenu works wierd with wordpress 3.5

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, contact-form-7, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I build this form on version 3.4 of wordpress
http://xn--5dbaaldanagj3al0n.org.il/

I implanted the `jquery ui` files like so

```
add_action( 'init', 'frontporch_enqueue_scripts' );
function frontporch_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'google-jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

        wp_register_script( 'ui-core', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/ui/jquery.ui.core.js',array('jquery'), true);
        wp_register_script( 'ui-position', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/ui/jquery.ui.position.js',array('jquery'), true);
        wp_register_script( 'ui-selectmenu', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js',array('jquery'), true);
        wp_register_script( 'ui-widget', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js',array('jquery'), true);       
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-core', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css', true);
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-selectmenu', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectmenu.css', true);
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-theme', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css', true);        
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-core' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-selectmenu' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-theme' );     
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google-jquery-ui' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ui-core' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ui-position' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ui-selectmenu' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ui-widget' );
    }       
}
```

and put the script in the `header.php` file like so

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#formlocation select").selectmenu();
    $("#formlocation input[type=text]").button();
});
</script>
```

And now when you go into [the site](http://xn--5dbaaldanagj3al0n.org.il/), you will see that the drop-down-lists look weird, the width suppose to be the same as all field and the selection is corrupt.
When i finished develop this form, everything was working smooth.

its because the 3.5 version comes with its own `jquery ui` files? is it the 3.5 at all??
i tried to take off the JS implementation but it didn't worked

would love to know whats going on in there
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try not to include jQuery UI multiple times and make sure the order of the files is correct.

So, use either the combinded CDN file and selectmenu js file only or include all needed jQuery UI plugins / widgets in the correct order: Core, Widget, Position, Selectmenu.